# Any idea in implementing ring buffer using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, memory, buffer

First, what I intend to do is to use memory to store the most recent "user update" records for each user. 
I am new to MySQL. How can I create tables in memory? 
In official website, it is said that we can set ENGINE = MEMORY when creating table. But the document claims that those tables in memory are always, for read, not for write.

I have simply no idea how to do that.

I am into this problems for a few days. I can't install memcache and any PHP extension in server as I'm not using Virtual Private Server, what I can do is just transfer scripts and files in httpdocs folder... I have also tried using flat files to store data to work as buffer/cache, but I found that I cannot write/create files in server's file directory due to denied permission, and I am not allowed to change this permission.
Using MySQL to buffer may be the only choice left for me. Hope someone can give me some hints.

Thank you.

p.s. I am using Linux Apache server running PHP, with MySQL as DB.

Comment: Can you better describe what it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually I am writing the server side scripts for my iPhone application, this app sends data to web server periodically. Those data will be stored in MySQL DB, but I also want the most recent, let say 30 data from each user is saved in memory for browser-side to access the recent data of users in higher speed.

Comment: You won't have enough memory to scale this the way you are proposing if you have sufficient enough users to require this.  Make a proper index and do this on a normal table.

Answer (score 0):

`ENGINE = MEMORY` tables can be used for both read or write.

The only thing to be careful of is that all data in a memory table disappears when the server crashes, is turned off, rebooted, etc.  (As you would expect for an in-memory table.)

Comment: What you mean is that rebooting server/server crashes will EMPTY the in-memory tables, but not DELETE them?

Comment: @user988988 Table schemas aren't stored along with the table itself - thus the table definition will be preserved (since it's not just stored in memory).

Answer (score 0):

You really should read carefully about MEMORY engine of MySQL. The data is stored in RAM so when the server is powered off, or rebooted, the RAM will be cleared, and data will be wiped. MEMORY table should be the fastest accessible table type of MySQL, but only stores temporary data, with no guarantee.

If I understood right, you are trying to make static cache of some sort of data generated from PHP, aren't you? The easiest way is to write them as solid file cache in your www directory, either HTML or JS. If you can't chmod your directory to writable, then store them in MySQL should be fine too, but only if that actually helps.

The idea of cache data is to: reduce SQL queries, reduce disk I/O, reduce code generation. But using MEMORY table costs too much memory usage. Store them in a normal MyISAM table should be fine too, and safe you a lot of background work.

However, there should be 2 things to consider: 1, if the cache does not exist when accessing; 2, if the cache is up-to-date.

Giving your result some sort of key should be a good idea, so the PHP checks for cached date first, if doesn't not exist, generate the cache, then display, or otherwise, display the cache directly.